# dma_alloc_coherent() returns error when the allocate size is over 4MB

Tags: drivers

I have tried both

virt_addr = dma_alloc_coherent(dma_dev, alloc_size, &phys_addr, GFP_KERNEL );

and
mypool = dma_pool_create("mypool", dma_dev, alloc_size, pool_align, 0);
virt_addr = dma_pool_alloc(mypool, GFP_ATOMIC , &phys_addr);

both failed, if alloc_size is over 4MB.

I also found that CONFIG_CMA is not set. ( Kernel version 5.19.0-32-generic)
How to allocate DMA buffer 512M in size?

Thank you,
dxyz_tiger

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu22.04.1, Kernel Version: Kernel version 5.19.0-32-generic